# WINDOWS APP DEVELOPMENT

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows, hyper-v

I have just started Windows Application Development and have installed Visual Studio 13 and Microsoft sdk 8.I am experiencing problems in Deploying the the app on the emulator.It says that Hyper V is not enabled on my pc. When i searched this error on the internet i found out thAt hyper v is windows 8.1 pro only feature and i have windows 8.1 single language and i don't want to upgrade because of monetary reasons.

So i just to know is there another way through which i can proceed app development on my computer either by using another emulator or any other way possible.

I read about oracle vm also but couldn't figure out to connect it to my visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop on a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) virtual machine which has a trial version of Windows 8 installed. You install the trial Windows 8, Visual Studio and SDKs on the VM, and do all development there. It's slower, but it works for us.

To make the creation and maintenance of the virtual machine image easier, there are some things you can do. First, start with a [vm image from the IE team](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools). Next you can install [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org) and find and install packages for Visual Studio and the SDKs you need. If you use source control and use these technologies, provisioning a new development VM should become very quick.

The recipe I use to make development Windows  boxes goes something like this:

## On your machine

1. Install Chocolatey

   - In elevated Powershell: `iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`
2. Run elevated: `choco install virtualbox`
3. Download [Win8.1](https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE11/Windows/IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip) virtual box image and run it

## On the Win8.1 VM

1. Install Chocolatey (as above)
2. Run the following in an elevated command to provision:

   - `choco install virtualbox.extensionpack`
   - `choco install visualstudio2013professional`
   - `choco install windows-sdk-8.1`
   - `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your second point in step-wise manner or could provide link to some blog or something. It would be very helpful and save a lot of my time!

Comment: Ok, added. Since you're new here, note that it is customary to upvote an answer when it is helpful.

Comment: .Tthanks!. Cant upvote your answer btw ,,,not enough reputation points as im new here.

Comment: Right, true. You should be able to "accept" it if you feel it is the best answer, however.